# Formulation of a method for visualizing exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

First I would recommend a picturebook [Puzzling through exact sequences](https://www.3blue1brown.com/blog/exact-sequence-picturebook) posted in the blog of 3Blue1Brown which gives a delightful visualization about exact sequences, chain complexes and so on. For me it is kind of weird that there is no discussion here about it in MSE.

I really recommend everyone to read its parts about snake lemma and zig-zag lemma, though I think there is a mistake in the part on induced homomorphism in homology. It gives some really nice intuition on what exactness really means and what really happens when we do diagram chasing.

While the picturebook is already intuitive, I wonder what can be done to further visualize and explain exactness along with the related concepts. **Can we formulate a method to systematically intepret the pictures in the picturebook, thus making them rigorous? Maybe we can develop theorems that explicitly relate operations on Abel groups with set operations?**

Also, I don't know whether there are other (perhaps better) visualization methods in addition to those in the picturebook. I would really appreciate it if anybody could provide some references on such methods.

Comment: +1 I have also been thinking about what exactly makes these pictures work as well as they do. I'm a little unclear on what exactly you mean when you ask about formulating a method to systematically interpret the pictures: it seems an object is a "box" and a morphism between two objects is equivalent to overlapping boxes (with heights included, to indicate direction of the morphism), etc.. Perhaps this isn't formal enough for what you have in mind. I personally think the question of taking a result and making a picture of it is more difficult (e.g. finding the picture of a commutative square).

Comment: Also, what is the mistake you're mentioning?

Comment: My gut reaction is that this all works precisely because of the first isomorphism theorem (and the fact that we have $0$). If we take as an axiom that a box represents an object, that overlapping boxes represent morphisms where the image is the overlap, and everything in the domain not in the overlap is sent to $0,$ the first isomorphism theorem precisely says that we can identify the overlap with the coimage of the morphism. Perhaps this is too simplistic to explain the effectiveness of the heuristic in full, but at a first glance it seems to me it is the key.

Comment: @Stahl I think there is a mistake in the picture of "morphism of cohomology groups". There are two disjoint boxes in that picture which I think might overlap.

Comment: @Stahl For example we should be able to write down a formal graphical syntax (i.e. the exact characterization of the legal configurations of boxes), and give an interpretation function from syntax to semantics (i.e. logical statements about abelian categories).